# Cannot install GRASS addons in GRASS 8.2 (Ubuntu jammy)

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I am trying to install the r.clip addon in GRASS 8.2 in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (jammy). I installed GRASS 8.2.0-1~jammy0 from [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and ideally need to use GRASS 8.2.0. I also have installed grass-dev and svn. When I try to install the r.clip addon, I get the following error:

```
g.extension r.clip
/usr/lib/grass82/scripts/g.extension:167: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
Fetching <r.clip> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/branches/grass8/src/raster/r.clip'
svn: E160013: '/OSGeo/grass-addons/branches/grass8/src/raster/r.clip' path not found
ERROR: GRASS Addons <r.clip> not found
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: This is strange because the URL exists. I have just compiled GRASS GIS 8.2.1 and it works for me. Question: current is 8.3, not 8.2. Any chance for you to avoid the outdated version?

Comment: For some reason I haven´t found yet, a code that was provided to me only works with GRASS 8.2 and not with GRASS 8.3. I used GRASS 8.2.0-1~jammy0 because that was the only 8.2* version available in ubuntugis-stable. I was trying to avoid compiling GRASS, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: What happens with that code when you use GRASS GIS 8.3? Maybe easy to update?

Comment: The code I use uses rgrass to call GRASS from R. I think it's not so easy to update. The error I get is: expected '>'
Opening and ending tag mismatch: description line 370 and des
Premature end of data in tag flag line 369
Error : 1: expected '>'
2: Opening and ending tag mismatch: description line 370 and des
3: Premature end of data in tag flag line 369

Error in parseGRASS(cmd, legacyExec = legacyExec) : g.region not parsed

Comment: I can install addons in GRASS 8.3, but not in 8.2.1 nor in 8.2.2-dev (I compiled them and got the same error). GRASS tmploc/PERMANENT:grass-8.2.1 > g.extension r.accumulate
Fetching <r.accumulate> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/branches/grass8/src/raster/r.accumulate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2024-January/083509.html) by Veronica Andreo in the GRASS user list, a workaround is to download the r.clip folder from the [GRASS GIS Addons Code Repository](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons) and install the extension
using the path to the folder.

```
g.extension extension=r.clip url=path/to/folder/r.clip
```

This issue is [fixed](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2024-January/083506.html) in GRASS 8.3. Github has sunset SVN protocol access and it's not possible to install addons through g.extension in Github in versions lower than 8.3.